# In Symfony2.4 container is null after using setController in onKernelController

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to redirect from the onKernelController event listener to another controller in my bundle. The redirection succeed but in the $newController the container is NULL so I can't really do any thing with it like rendering pages.
Why is the container NULL when it's been created like this? and how can I inject the container service to the $newController in this case?

Thanks! :)

**The final working version of the event listener:**

```
namespace MyApp\MainBundle\EventListener;

use MyApp\MainBundle\Interfaces\UserCheckInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ControllerListener
{
    private $resolver;

    /**
     * @param ControllerResolver $resolver The injected controller_resolver service
     */
    public function __construct($resolver)
    {
        $this->resolver = $resolver;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller))
        {
            // not an object but a different kind of callable. Do nothing
            return;
        }

        /* @var $controllerObject Controller  */
        $controllerObject = $controller[0];

        if ( $controllerObject instanceof UserCheckInterface )
        {
            $newRequest = $event->getRequest()->duplicate(null, null, array('_controller' => 'MyApp\MainBundle\Controller\ErrorController::notLoggedInAction'));

            /* @var $newController Controller  */
            $newController = $this->resolver->getController($newRequest);
            $event->setController($newController);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the config.yml**

```
kernel.listener.ControllerListener:
        class: MyApp\MainBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener
        arguments: [ "@controller_resolver" ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component resolver (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver) does not know anything about the container.

Instead, the Symfony FrameworkBundle provides Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver which is container aware.  It's worth taking a look at the code to see where setContainer is being called.

Inject the controller_resolver service into your listener then use it instead of creating a new resolver.

Comment: OK I changed the code so the controller_resolver will be injected to the event listener. I guess that's the proper way to this also edited my example.

Answer (score 2):

OK... I found the answer...

When creating the $newController like I did the container by default is NULL and need to be set with the container of the original controller like this

```
$newController[0]->setContainer($controllerObject->get("service_container"));
```

Comment: Nope.  You still have something wrong.  The framework resolver will set the container for you.  I suspect you still have a new ControllerReolver statement in your code.

Comment: Hey!!! :)
Thank you so much!! you are right... the framework does set the container now without me needing to set it I fixed the code and uploaded the entire event listener.